# Passing PHP objects and methods as strings to FormAPI

Tags: forms

When working with [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), how do you pass a method to the [FormAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7)'s [['#after_build']](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build) feature?

For example, how can I pass $myObject->_my_after_build_function to [['#after_build']](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build)?

---

**Non-OOP exampe of what I would like to accomplish:**

```
$form['#after_build'][] = '_my_after_build_function';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$form['#after_build']` is handled from the following code, contained in [form_builder()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_builder/7).

```
  if (isset($element['#after_build']) && !isset($element['#after_build_done'])) {
    foreach ($element['#after_build'] as $function) {
      $element = $function($element, $form_state);
    }
    $element['#after_build_done'] = TRUE;
  }
```

Differently from other cases, Drupal doesn't use [function_exists()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check if the function exists. This means that using the following code works, since PHP 5.2.3.

```
$form['#after_build'][] = 'MyClass::_my_after_build_function';
```

As side note, it would work also with closures.

```
$build_function = function($element, $form_state) {
  // …
};

$form['#after_build'][] = $build_function;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to call a function that will call

```
$myObject->_my_after_build_function();
```

One way that won't work most likely.

```
$method_name = _my_after_build_function;  
"$myObject->{$method_name}"
```

Another shot in the dark that might work if using PHP 5.2.3+ http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php.

```
"myObjectClassName::_my_after_build_function"
```

You can try the above 2 methods but with a `&` in front of it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Creating a function that loads the method worked.  Thank you.